# Transpose a matrix(python 3)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, module, transpose

I have a module wrote in python to input a matrix that looks like that:

```
matrix = []
loop = True
while loop:
    line = input()
    if not line:       #the way it works is that you enter value separated by a space and enter a blank line to finish inputing the matrix
        loop = False
    values = line.split()
    row = [int(value) for value in values]
    matrix.append(row)

print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in matrix]))
```

The last line is just to print the matrix like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I would like to be able to transpose the matrix in another module,I tried this so far:

```
def transpose_matrix(matrix):
     zip(*matrix)
     return matrix
```

But it actually doesnt work it doesnt have any effect on the actual matrix,the matrix stays the same,and I dont get it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would get the matrix in the following manner, to avoid the empty list in the end:

```
matrix = []

while True:
    line = input()
    if not line:
        break
    values = line.split()
    row = [int(value) for value in values]
    matrix.append(row)
```

as for transposing it, the best way is to leave it to numpy:

```
import numpy as np

transposed_matrix = np.transpose(np.array(matrix))
```

if for any reason you would like to avoid numpy (which is not advisable), you can use:

```
transposed_matrix = []

for line in zip(*matrix):
    transposed_matrix.append(line)
```